# Should I go for Multisite or separate WP Installation?

Tags: multisite, customization, installation

I'm developing an article site where an user can register and post the articles and the URL would be like **http://domain.com/articles/category-name/article-name**

The site will also be having a blog under **http://domain.com/blog/** And the blog section will only be accessed by site owners and not by any registered users.

I want the blog URL to be like http://domain.com/blog/post-name and not to be like http://domain.com/articles...

So should I go for a separate WP Installation or enable Multisite for this URL structure ?

Any other better options/ideas are always welcome. **I don't want to do an installation on a subdomain like blog.domain.com**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally choosing separate WP installations means that your websites won't have anything in common.

Choosing Multisite installation enables you some sort of centralization. Your blogs usually are separate (eg. different domains / themes), but they may share something.

According to your description you might want consider a single installation. It is possible to create the described URL structure using Wordpress Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies. For the registered users functionality, you could adapt the Contributor user role to your needs, so users, who are Contributors are limited only to posting articles to your website.

Comment: Thanks for the generous reply. But should I go for Wordpress Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies to get the required URL structure ?

Comment: Well, from your description it seems that your only requirement is the URL structure. This is easily achieved with Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies. Go for it :-)

Comment: Will follow your advice and keep updated. Thanks to all.